# flexbox and tailwindcss : Cards Not Displaying Responsively in a Row as Expected

Tags: css, flexbox, tailwind-css

I'm trying to reuse a card component. I want to show max 3 cards in a row on large device and on medium i want to show 2 cards in a row but it's not working

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const MainNewsCard = ({ //Imports}) => {
 return (
    <Link
      className="flex-1 flex flex-col w-full md:w-1/2 lg:w-1/3 mb-8"
      to={`/post/${title}/${id}`}
    >
      <div className="relative overflow-hidden flex-1">
        <div
          className="h-[280px] bg-cover bg-center flex-1"
          style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${image})` }}
        ></div>
        <div className="absolute inset-0 flex flex-col justify-between p-4 text-white ">
          <div>
            <p className="text-xl font-manrope leading-normal text-color-red text-right -mt-3">
              {category}
            </p>
          </div>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="mx-5 mt-3">
        //title and description
      </div>
    </Link>
  );
};

export default MainNewsCard;
```

this is the map function

```
<div className="flex flex-col sm:flex-row justify-center items-center gap-4 mb-10 ">
        {categoryPosts.map((post) => (
          <MainNewsCard key={post.id} {...post} />
        ))}
      </div>
```

for small device it works as expected but on medium and large device it doesn't shows 2 and 3 post, it shows all the post in the same row

Comment: i want to do it with flexbox

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to let the browser layout engine know that you'd like the flex children to be able to wrap to a new line by applying `flex-wrap: wrap` to the flex layout parent. Furthermore, the `flex-1` class applies `flex-basis: 0%` (amongst other things) which would mean that the flex children would try to all fit into one row. You'd want to look at applying `flex-basis` rather than `width` above the `sm:` breakpoint, since `flex-basis` is considered over `width` in a horizontal flex layout.

However, if we have a look at these two changes, we'll see that now it won't ever be three column:

```js
const Link = ({ to, children, ...props }) => <a href={to} {...props}>{children}</a>

const MainNewsCard = ({ title, image, category, id }) => {
 return (
    <Link
      className="flex-1 flex flex-col w-full sm:basis-full md:basis-1/2 lg:basis-1/3 mb-8"
      to={`/post/${title}/${id}`}
    >
      <div className="relative overflow-hidden flex-1">
        <div
          className="h-[280px] bg-cover bg-center flex-1"
          style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${image})` }}
        ></div>
        <div className="absolute inset-0 flex flex-col justify-between p-4 text-white ">
          <div>
            <p className="text-xl font-manrope leading-normal text-color-red text-right -mt-3">
              {category}
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="mx-5 mt-3">
        //title and description
      </div>
    </Link>
  );
};

function App() {
  const categoryPosts = [
    {
      id: 0,
      title: 'foo',
      category: 'foo',
      image: 'https://picsum.photos/280/280?0',
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      title: 'bar',
      category: 'bar',
      image: 'https://picsum.photos/280/280?1',
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: 'baz',
      category: 'baz',
      image: 'https://picsum.photos/280/280?0',
    },
  ];

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col sm:flex-row sm:flex-wrap justify-center items-center gap-4 mb-10 ">
      {categoryPosts.map((post) => (
        <MainNewsCard key={post.id} {...post} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}


ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('app')).render(<App/>);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-8Q6Y9XnTbOE+JNvjBQwJ2H8S+UV4uA6hiRykhdtIyDYZ2TprdNmWOUaKdGzOhyr4dCyk287OejbPvwl7lrfqrQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-MOCpqoRoisCTwJ8vQQiciZv0qcpROCidek3GTFS6KTk2+y7munJIlKCVkFCYY+p3ErYFXCjmFjnfTTRSC1OHWQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.5"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

This is because the `flex-basis` and the `gap`s equate to more than the parent's width, thus the last item will always wrap. We'd need to compensate for the `gap-4` in the children's `flex-basis` values:

```js
const Link = ({ to, children, ...props }) => <a href={to} {...props}>{children}</a>

const MainNewsCard = ({ title, image, category, id }) => {
 return (
    <Link
      className="flex-1 flex flex-col w-full sm:basis-full md:basis-[calc(50%-theme(spacing.4)/2)] lg:basis-[calc(33.33%-theme(spacing.4))] mb-8"
      to={`/post/${title}/${id}`}
    >
      <div className="relative overflow-hidden flex-1">
        <div
          className="h-[280px] bg-cover bg-center flex-1"
          style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${image})` }}
        ></div>
        <div className="absolute inset-0 flex flex-col justify-between p-4 text-white ">
          <div>
            <p className="text-xl font-manrope leading-normal text-color-red text-right -mt-3">
              {category}
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="mx-5 mt-3">
        //title and description
      </div>
    </Link>
  );
};

function App() {
  const categoryPosts = [
    {
      id: 0,
      title: 'foo',
      category: 'foo',
      image: 'https://picsum.photos/280/280?0',
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      title: 'bar',
      category: 'bar',
      image: 'https://picsum.photos/280/280?1',
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: 'baz',
      category: 'baz',
      image: 'https://picsum.photos/280/280?0',
    },
  ];

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col sm:flex-row sm:flex-wrap justify-center items-center gap-4 mb-10 ">
      {categoryPosts.map((post) => (
        <MainNewsCard key={post.id} {...post} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}


ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('app')).render(<App/>);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-8Q6Y9XnTbOE+JNvjBQwJ2H8S+UV4uA6hiRykhdtIyDYZ2TprdNmWOUaKdGzOhyr4dCyk287OejbPvwl7lrfqrQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-MOCpqoRoisCTwJ8vQQiciZv0qcpROCidek3GTFS6KTk2+y7munJIlKCVkFCYY+p3ErYFXCjmFjnfTTRSC1OHWQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.5"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

You could also consider using a grid layout instead, in which you can dictate the column count more explicitly on the parent element:

```js
const Link = ({ to, children, ...props }) => <a href={to} {...props}>{children}</a>

const MainNewsCard = ({ title, image, category, id }) => {
 return (
    <Link
      className="flex flex-col mb-8"
      to={`/post/${title}/${id}`}
    >
      <div className="relative overflow-hidden flex-1">
        <div
          className="h-[280px] bg-cover bg-center flex-1"
          style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${image})` }}
        ></div>
        <div className="absolute inset-0 flex flex-col justify-between p-4 text-white ">
          <div>
            <p className="text-xl font-manrope leading-normal text-color-red text-right -mt-3">
              {category}
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="mx-5 mt-3">
        //title and description
      </div>
    </Link>
  );
};

function App() {
  const categoryPosts = [
    {
      id: 0,
      title: 'foo',
      category: 'foo',
      image: 'https://picsum.photos/280/280?0',
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      title: 'bar',
      category: 'bar',
      image: 'https://picsum.photos/280/280?1',
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: 'baz',
      category: 'baz',
      image: 'https://picsum.photos/280/280?0',
    },
  ];

  return (
    <div className="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3 gap-4 mb-10 ">
      {categoryPosts.map((post) => (
        <MainNewsCard key={post.id} {...post} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}


ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('app')).render(<App/>);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-8Q6Y9XnTbOE+JNvjBQwJ2H8S+UV4uA6hiRykhdtIyDYZ2TprdNmWOUaKdGzOhyr4dCyk287OejbPvwl7lrfqrQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-MOCpqoRoisCTwJ8vQQiciZv0qcpROCidek3GTFS6KTk2+y7munJIlKCVkFCYY+p3ErYFXCjmFjnfTTRSC1OHWQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.5"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```